# How to resolve Plesk Error : Internal error: filemng failed

Tags: hosting, plesk

my website is no longer accessible. When I try to load my plesk file manager, im presented with the following error below.

`Internal error: filemng failed: Unable to lookup SID for name TestWebSite: (1332) No mapping between account names and security IDs was done. (Error code 1)`

I believe i'm on shared hosting so I can't RDP to the server. Any idea's what other options I have or how to resolve this issue/

Answer (score 0):

Fix it in CLI with following commands:

"%plesk_dir%\bin\repair.exe" --repair-webspace-system-users -webspace-name example.com
"%plesk_dir%\bin\repair.exe" --repair-webspace-security -webspace-name example.com